# Multiple Json files conversion to feature class using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, file-geodatabase, json

I am a beginner in Python.
I am migrating from visual basic.

I have multiple .json files that I want to convert them all in one script using python to a file Geodatabase:

What is the issue in the following code

```
    # Esri start of added imports
    import sys, os, arcpy
    import arcpy
    import os.path
    import os
 
   try:
for x in range(100):
  
    gdb=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\buildings_cabinets"
    arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion("C:\buildings_cab\ x + ".json", 
    os.path.join("C:\buildings_cab\yu.gdb", x + ".json))
   

 except Exception as e:
    arcpy.AddMessage(e.message)
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your try block, change it to the following:

```
gdb=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/buildings_cabinets"
arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion("C:/buildings_cab/{}.json".format(x),
os.path.join("C:/buildings_cab/yu.gdb", x))
```

**What did I change?**

1. I used a *format string* to help dynamically populate your first argument in `arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion()`. `"C:/buildings_cab/{}.json".format(x)` is processed into `C:/buildings_cab/x.json"` which I believe is what you were looking for. You were on the right track using string concatenation with `+`, but you need to make sure you have properly terminated each substring with another `"`.
   For example: `"C:/buildings_cab/" + x + ".json"`. Either way works, but I used a format string syntax for 'cleaner code'.
2. I replaced your `\` into `/`. Why is this important? A single `\` used within a string will combine with some characters to form an **escape character** to allow us to inject an 'illegal' character (i.e. has a special function) such as `"` into a string. Using a `\` in a string will check to see if the immediately following character combines with it to form one of these escape characters. This is fine if the characters following your `\` don't create one of these escape characters or you intended to use it as an escape character, but in the case of your code `\b` is the escape character for backspace. If you try printing `"C:\building_cab\yu.gdb"` for instance, you will get `C:\x08uilding_cab\\yu.gdb` where `x08` is the UTF-8 sequence for backspace used in a string. If you wish to use `\` in your file paths, it is good form to use a raw string. Simply prefix your string with an `r` and it will ignore this special use of `\` and include it literally in your string. Example `r"C:\building_cab\yu.gdb"`
3. Lastly, I fixed your path join in your final line. You cannot insert a .json file into a geodatabase, so the parameter is not looking for a .json, rather a **Feature Class**. Feature classes have no extensions, so you can simply join `"C:/building_cab/yu.gdb"` and `x` to get the feature class `C:/building_cab/yu.gdb/x`.

**Note:** I did not test the code, but hopefully it gets you going.